# Ansible: how to get host specific variable value by hostname

Tags: ansible

I'd like to insert initial values to a client's sqlite by Ansible and the values are different for every host.

I created myrole/vars/main.yml:

```
hostname1:
    id: id_1
    value: value_1
hostname2:
    id: id_2
    value: value_2
```

I want to to get it by `{{ {{ inventory_hostname }}.id }}` and insert the template of .sql, but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve by modify your variable like this:

```
clients:
  hostname1:
    id: id_1
    value: value_1
  hostname2:
    id: id_2
    value: value_2
```

Then in your template:

```
{{ clients[inventory_hostname].id }}
```

where `inventory_hostname` will be `hostname1`,`hostname2` etc.

Hope that help you.

Answer (score 2):

A role should not include host specific configuration. Instead store host specific configuration in host vars. Create a file for every host relative to your playbook in the `host_vars` directory, e.g. `host_vars/hostname1` with the content

```
id: id_1
value: value_1
```

This file is automatically loaded by Ansible and you can use the vars `id` and `value` right away.

If you need to access the variables from other hosts or from local tasks, you can access them through the global `hostvars` dict:

```
hostvars[inventory_hostname].id
```