# remote1 uses facts of remote2

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I seem to miss some basic concept of ansible and can't get it right.

My hosts:

```
[win10]
dev1
mep1
```

my role has a task to create a link on the desktop, to do so, I need to know the username, preferably also the path to the user profile.

The versions of my task I tried:

```
- name: create desktop shortcut
  win_shortcut:
    src: "{{ ansible_env.ProgramFiles }}\\chrome\\chrome.exe"
    args: "--dev"
    dest: "C:\\Users\\{{ ansible_user }}\\Desktop\\chrome.lnk"
    state: present
```

```
- name: create desktop shortcut
  win_shortcut:
    src: "{{ ansible_env.ProgramFiles }}\\chrome\\chrome.exe"
    args: "--dev"
    dest: "{{ setup.ansible_facts.ansible_user_dir }}\\Desktop\\chrome.lnk"
```

When I run my role, the variables represent the those of the "dev1" remote and always fail on "mep1" remote, because the usernames are different.
Also, gathering facts runs twice, so I believe I fail on a ansible concept.

```
PLAY [win10] *******************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [dev1]
ok: [mep1]

PLAY [win10] *******************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [dev1]
ok: [mep1]

TASK [install_chrome : create desktop shortcut] **************************
fatal: [dev1]: FAILED! => {"args": "--dev", "changed": true, "description": "", "dest": "C:\\Users\\tom\\Desktop\\chrome.lnk", "directory": "", "hotkey": "", "icon": ",0", "msg": "Failed to create shortcut 'C:\\Users\\tom\\Desktop\\chrome.lnk'. (Unable to save shortcut \"C:\\Users\\tom\\Desktop\\chrome.lnk\".)", "src": "C:\\Program Files\\chrome\\chrome.exe", "state": "present", "windowstyle": "normal"}
ok: [mep1]
```

Please push me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to run the ansible playbook to only one of the hosts? If yes you can limit the inventory when executing the playbook with the host you need.
Example:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml --limit dev1
```

Comment: thanks but I want to run the playbook against 2 or more remote machines. Each machine should use the fact of their own machine, and not of any other.

Comment: There are some ways how to use variables assigned to hosts. I would suggest declaring variables per host. Links: 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37832916/ansible-how-to-get-host-specific-variable-value-by-hostname] or 
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html

Comment: My understanding was, that my role is using the gathered facts of one remote on the other, and that the task is failing because of that.
I found out the the Problem is somewhere else, sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the error output was that my play was using the facts of one remote host on the other. In my case, the user name and the user profile location.
Seems my play was correct.
The problem was that the "Desktop" is simply not in "C:\User\Username" but somewhere else.

Sorry for anyone coming across this ;)

Comment: Writing this question down helped me understand my actual problem :D